# Cannot call Python script from macro using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am working with xlwings v0.25.0 and have the matching version for the Excel add-in. I am also using Office 365 and Python 3.7.4.

I am trying to run a Python script, `testing_xlwings.py` from a vba macro in Excel.

```
import xlwings as xw

def main():
    sheet = xw.Book.caller().sheets[0]
    sheet.range('B10').value = 'IT WORKED!!!'
```

I have assigned the macro to the button and when I click to run, I receive the following error `Compile error: Sub or Function not defined`.
My sub for the macro looks like this:

```
Sub Run_xlwings()
    RunPython "import testing_xlwings.py; testing_xlwings.main()"
End Sub
```

If I change `sheet = xw.Book.caller().sheets[0]` to `sheet = xw.Book('testing_workbook.xlsm').sheets[0]` the script executes and the text is placed in the Excel file.

I have also downloaded the Monte Carlo example from the xlwings [examples](https://www.xlwings.org/examples) page. When I open the file and try to run the .py script using the macro, I receive this error: `AttributeError: module 'xlwings.utlis' has no attribute 'prepare_sys_path'`

What do I need to change to run the script from the macro?

Comment: Can you please open an issue on https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the macro to the call the Python script by pressing `Alt` + `F11` to bring up the VBA editor. From the toolbar across the top, I selected `Tools` -> `References` and I ticked the checkbox for `xlwings`. After I clicked OK I was able to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

if you still get error... try to install a previous version of xlwings.
On the console type:

```
pip install xlwings==0.27.2

xlwings addin install
```